# Cursor in contenteditable: size and position

Tags: jquery, css

The cursor in an empty contenteditable div has a estrange behavior. In Safari and Firefox it is too big and it is out of its place.  It works well in Chrome. I could not check in ie.

I know I could solve it if I delete the padding and/or inline-block. But I need these features.

First of all, I would like to understand why this happen, then if there is any way to solve it (to have the cursor the same size and position than the letters inside the div)

```js
$(function(){
 $(".note").focus();  
})
```

```css
.note {
 width:200px;
 text-align:left;
 outline:none;
 padding:10px; 
 display:inline-block;
 background:lightGrey;
 
 font-size:14px;
 cursor:text;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="note" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: Interesting. It disappears in Firefox when you set `line-height: 0px`, but that doesn't help in Safari (and would be a nasty hack anyways).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I remember, I faced that problem on Firefox when writing WYSIWYG editors. If you write something, then select all content (press Ctlr+a) and delete it the problem disappears. If you will check the editor content after this operation you found a `<br>` tag. The below workaround uses this fact and just put it initially:

```js
$(function(){
 $(".note").focus();  
})
```

```css
.note {
 width:200px;
 text-align:left;
 outline:none;
 padding:10px; 
 display:inline-block;
 background:lightGrey;
 
 font-size:14px;
 cursor:text;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="note" contenteditable="true"><br></div>
```

Comment: Interresting but what about setting focus on DIV on FF? Any workaround?

Comment: My bad, was testing it on jsFiddle, looks like specific issue with embeded iframe there: http://jsfiddle.net/1h73bsw8  but works here: http://jsfiddle.net/1h73bsw8/show/  Not sure what's going on

Comment: It's better to use contentEditable div rather than iframe for wysiwyg editors; in particular iframe may cause some additional problems in combination with systems like jsfiddle.